# Find the most common entry in an array

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, time-complexity

You are given a 32-bit unsigned integer array with length up to 2<sup>32</sup>, with the property that more than half of the entries in the array are equal to N, for some 32-bit unsigned  integer N. Find N looking at each number in the array only once and using at most 2 kB of memory.

Your solution must be deterministic, and guaranteed to find N.

Comment: If anyone is looking for a correct approach for this classical problem in theory of streaming algorithms, take a look at [my detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36243686/1090562)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Keep one integer for each bit, and increment this collection appropriately for each integer in the array.

At the end, some of the bits will have a count higher than half the length of the array - those bits determine N. Of course, the count will be higher than the number of times N occurred, but that doesn't matter. The important thing is that any bit which isn't part of N *cannot* occur more than half the times (because N has over half the entries) and any bit which is part of N *must* occur more than half the times (because it will occur every time N occurs, and any extras).

(No code at the moment - about to lose net access. Hopefully the above is clear enough though.)

Comment: I didn't care about the question until I read your answer.  Jon Skeet I salute you.

Comment: Boyer-Moore is better, but this is really nice too.

Comment: @Toro: 32 integers, each of size 32 bits, plus whatever local variables are required.

Comment: beautiful. then you just go just take a 32 bit int and through the new array and if element i is > orig_arr_len/2 then you set the corresponding bit in the int, else let it be 0.

Comment: Can you distinguish between "there is no element with count > 2^31" and "the element with count > 2^31 is zero"?

Comment: @Gabe: The question states that there *is* an element with more than half the elements equal to some value.

Answer (score 43):

[Boyer and Moore's "Linear Time Majority Vote Algorithm"](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/best-ideas/mjrty/index.html) - go down the array maintaining your current guess at the answer.

Comment: A rather interesting algorithm.  Same complexity as the accepted solution, O(n) that is, but with significantly lower runtime due to less math.

Comment: Great algorithm. I found it amazing that 1) my one-line sentence actually describes is fully and 2) the sentence looks like a first-stab naive attempt at the algoritm, an attempt that cannot work.

Comment: @buti-oxa Does this algorithm work for the sequence "A A A C C B B". Im somehow unable to make it work.

Comment: @Pavan No, because "more than half of the entries in the array are equal to N" condition is not met.

Comment: @buti-oxa Ah!. That explains it. Thanks for ur response :)

Comment: This is extremely cool.  I thought through the puzzle before reading the answers and came up with counting-the-bits answer above, thinking myself pretty clever.  Then this one showed me how clever I could have been.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with only two variables.

```java
public uint MostCommon(UInt32[] numberList)
{
    uint suspect = 0;
    int suspicionStrength = -1; 
    foreach (uint number in numberList)
    {
        if (number==suspect)
        {
            suspicionStrength++;
        }
        else
        {
            suspicionStrength--;
        }

        if (suspicionStrength<=0)
        {
            suspect = number;
        }
    }
    return suspect;
}
```

Make the first number the suspect number, and continue looping through the list. If the number matches, increase the suspicion strength by one; if it doesn't match, lower the suspicion strength by one. If the suspicion strength hits 0 the current number becomes the suspect number. This will *not* work to find the most common number, only a number that is more than 50% of the group. Resist the urge to add a check if `suspicionStrength` is greater than half the list length - it will always result in more total comparisons.

P.S. I have not tested this code - use it at your own peril.

Answer (score 4):

Pseudo code (notepad C++ :-)) for Jon's algorithm:

```
int lNumbers = (size_of(arrNumbers)/size_of(arrNumbers[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < lNumbers; i++)
  for (int bi = 0; bi < 32; bi++)
    arrBits[i] = arrBits[i] + (arrNumbers[i] & (1 << bi)) == (1 << bi) ? 1 : 0;

int N = 0;

for (int bc = 0; bc < 32; bc++)
  if (arrBits[bc] > lNumbers/2)
    N = N | (1 << bc);
```

Comment: Lots of problems with your arithmetic and [default] signed int types if the array is very large.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that if the sequence `a0, a1, . . . , an−1` contains a leader, then after removing a pair of
elements of different values, the remaining sequence still has the same leader. Indeed, if we
remove two different elements then only one of them could be the leader. The leader in the
new sequence occurs more than `n/2 − 1` = `(n−2)/2`
times. Consequently, it is still the leader of the
new sequence of `n − 2` elements.

Here is a Python implementation, with O(n) time complexity:

```python
def goldenLeader(A):
    n = len(A)
    size = 0
    for k in xrange(n):
        if (size == 0):
            size += 1
            value = A[k]
        else:
            if (value != A[k]):
                size -= 1
            else:
                size += 1
    candidate = -1
    if (size > 0):
        candidate = value
    leader = -1
    count = 0
    for k in xrange(n):
        if (A[k] == candidate):
            count += 1
    if (count > n // 2):
        leader = candidate
    return leader
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard problem in streaming algorithms (where you have a huge (potentially infinite) stream of data) and you have to calculate some statistics from this stream, passing through this stream once.

---

Clearly you can approach it with hashing or sorting, but with potentially infinite stream you clearly run out of memory. So you have to do something smart here.

---

**The majority element is the element that occurs more than half of the size of the array**. This means that the majority element occurs more than all other elements combined or if you count the number of times, majority element appears, and subtract the number of all other elements, you will get a positive number.

So if you count the number of some element, and subtract the number of all other elements and get the number 0 - then your original element can't be a majority element. This if the basis for a correct algorithm:

*Have two variables, counter and possible element. Iterate the stream, if the counter is 0 - your overwrite the possible element and initialize the counter, if the number is the same as possible element - increase the counter, otherwise decrease it.* Python code:

```python
def majority_element(arr):
    counter, possible_element = 0, None
    for i in arr:
        if counter == 0:
            possible_element, counter = i, 1
        elif i == possible_element:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter -= 1

    return possible_element
```

It is clear to see that the algorithm is `O(n)` with a very small constant before `O(n)` (like 3). Also it looks like the space complexity is `O(1)`, because we have only three variable initialized. The problem is that one of these variables is a counter which potentially can grow up to `n` (when the array consists of the same numbers). And to store the number `n` you need `O(log (n))` space. So **from theoretical point of view** it is `O(n)` time and `O(log(n))` space. **From practical**, you can fit 2^128 number in a longint and this number of elements in the array is unimaginably huge.

Also note that the algorithm works only if there is a majority element. If such element does not exist it will still return some number, which will surely be wrong. (it is easy to modify the algorithm to tell whether the majority element exists)

History channel: this algorithm was invented somewhere in 1982 by Boyer, Moore and called [Boyer–Moore majority vote algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

I have recollections of this algorithm, which might or might not follow the 2K rule.  It might need to be rewritten with stacks and the like to avoid breaking the memory limits due to function calls, but this might be unneeded since it only ever has a logarithmic number of such calls.  Anyhow, I have vague recollections from college or a recursive solution to this which involved divide and conquer, the secret being that when you divide the groups in half, at least one of the halves still has more than half of its values equal to the max.  The basic rule when dividing is that you return two candidate top values, one of which is the top value and one of which is some other value (that may or may not be 2nd place).  I forget the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 0):

Proof of correctness for buti-oxa / Jason Hernandez's answer, assuming Jason's answer is the same as buti-oxa's answer and both work the way the algorithm described should work:

We define adjusted suspicion strength as being equal to suspicion strength if top value is selected or -suspicion strength if top value is not selected.  Every time you pick the right number, the current adjusted suspicion strength increases by 1.  Each time you pick a wrong number, it either drops by 1 or increases by 1, depending on if the wrong number is currently selected.  So, the minimum possible ending adjusted suspicion strength is equal to number-of[top values] - number-of[other values]