# O(n) algorithm to find out the element appearing more than n/2 times

Tags: c++

I was asked in an interview to give an O(n) algorithm to print an element that appears more than n/2 times in an array, if there is such an element. n is the size of the array.
I don't have any clue on how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you just use a hash and count the number of elements as you scan through the array?

Comment: Not sure. I think there should be a simpler and elegant solution.

Comment: Oh. You didn't ask for most elegant, just O(n)

Comment: @Samuel: how is that not implied? You could have done a lot worse ;)

Comment: @sje397 Well it sounded like the OP didn't know how to do it in O(n) or wasn't clear what that meant, I hesitate posting an algorithm on SO when "elagance" or "most efficient" is involved :D

Comment: @Samuel Thank you for the answer. But it looks like the interviewer had Boyer's Voting algorithm in mind since n/2 is mentioned. I should not have used "elegant" there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's the [Boyer's Voting algorithm](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/index.html).

It's also O(1) in space!.

**Edit**

For those complaining about the site color scheme (like me) ... [here is the original paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/boyer/mjrty.ps.Z).

Comment: The colour scheme on that link is horrible.

Comment: Here's some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780937/linear-time-voting-algorithm-i-dont-get-it

Comment: Nice read. Took me a minute to find the subtle logic which avoids maintaining independent counts: "..._increment or decrement the counter_ according to whether e is the current candidate..."

Comment: @pst Boyer has several of those subtleties in his works. Look for example his string matching algorithm. A jewel!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: Thanks!  @chrisaycock that link was informative. I was having similar doubt.

Answer (score 0):

In psuedocode:

```
int n = array.length
Hash<elementType,int> hash
foreach element in array
    hash[element] += 1
foreach entry in hash
    if entry.value > n/2
        print entry.key
        break
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be considered O(2n) ?

Comment: @Eric This would be `O(n+m)`. By the way, there is no such thing as `O(2n)` as big-O doesn't use constant coefficients; in such a case it's just `O(n)`.

Comment: @chrisaycock. Let `m` be the number of entries in `hash`, and `n` be the number of elements in `array`. `m <= n` so assuming no hash collisions, this algorithm does indeed take `O(n)` time. (If we allow for hash collisions, it takes `O(n^2)` time worst case.)

Comment: @chrisaycock - There is such a thing as O(2n)... its just the same as O(n). It is still a valid statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's also the median value, which takes O(n) to find using the [median-of-medians algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm). In C++ you can do this in one line:

```
std::nth_element(begin, begin + n/2, begin + n)
```

Comment: Note though that `std::nth_element` is only required to be expected O(n) and so likely does not use the median-of-medians algorithm. The quick-sort like selection tends to be better in practice than m-of-m.