# How to find the most frequent element in a stream of numbers with additions and deletions allowed

Tags: algorithm, hash, heap

I am new to the forum but I have read the guidelines and checked for duplicates( This is the closest I found :([How to find the most frequent word in a word stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547686/how-to-find-the-most-frequent-word-in-a-word-stream)) but this searches for numbers that occur more than 51 % of the time. Please point me to a duplicate if it already exists.

So my questions is given a stream of numbers, find the number that occurs most frequently. 
For example : 2,3,4,2,5 : Ans = 2. 
This is easy but what happens if I can delete and add new numbers. 
Example :  2,3,5,3,4,2,2 : Max = 2
Delete(2) : Max = 2 ; Delete(2) : Max = 3 ...

I have thought of a Max heap Along with a Hash Table that contains pointers to each node in the heap so that updation is O(log n) and finding the max is O(1). Is there a better solution ?

Comment: Try following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740371/finding-the-max-repeated-element-in-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested mostly in fast updates, you can use any data structure that associates keys (the integers) with values (each integer's current appearance count). "Adding" and "removing" integers will be simply handled by incrementing and decrementing the appearance count.

For containers based on binary trees the operations would be O(logN) while for a hashtable it would be O(1). In each case "find the maximum" would be O(N).

If you are interested mostly in fast "find the maximum" then your proposed solution is as good as it gets.

Comment: I am mostly interested in optimizing the "find the maximum" , so just a Hash Table won't work since Finding the max would be O(N). Thanks for your input !

Answer (score 0):

Got this question for a FAANG interview today.
It is achievable using 2 HashMaps and an int/long variable for topFrequency.

```
 - HashMap 1: key==Element, value==Frequency
 - HashMap 2: key==Frequency, value==HashSet<Element> // if duplicate elements are allowed replace value to value==HashMap<Element, Frequency>
 - update topFrequency when its corresponding HashSet (in HashMap2) becomes empty (when frequency is decreased hence not required here) or a better frequency comes.
```

**Interview question**:
Find Top 1 frequent element in a stream. But the problem was framed in a different manner. Implement apis:

- postTweet(userId, tweetId, message)
- like(userId, tweetId)
- unlike(userId, tweetId)
- getTopLikedTweet(userId)